# Range object InputBox problem (empty value)

Tags: excel, vba, range, inputbox

I have a macro that requires user to select range, and then it carries on:

```
Dim rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell", "Make it happen!", Type:=8)
```

And when range is selected, everything works great.
But when user just presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without selecting any range, I get error:

[image: There is a problem with this formula.]

I tried to check `rng.value`, `rng.count`, but without any luck.
I just want a simple Exit Sub if nothing is selected.

Comment: Use proper error handling instead of ```on error resume next```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I recommend to read: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling) • Never use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling.

Comment: Got it. What you're receiving is the expected behavior in Excel. Pressing Enter wouldn't allow you to continue. Error handling would apply for when user presses Cancel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how you would use the `InputBox` properly to select a range. It will throw a message box *"user pressed cancel"* or the range the user selected.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InputBoxExample()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell", "Make it happen!", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "user pressed cancel"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "user selected " & rng.Address, False, False
    End If

End Sub
```

If you press <kbd>OK</kbd> without selecting anything you get the message that you showed in your question. This is a behavior of the `InputBox` and the message is not from VBA, therefore it cannot be changed. Actually the reason of the message is that the user is forced to either enter a valid address (or formula that resolves in an address) or press cancel to abort selecting.

What you actually *can* do is supressing **all** alerts of that box. But not the one specifically.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell", "Make it happen!", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This will turn **all** alerts off that come from that InputBox. So if you choose anything invalid (or nothing) the <kbd>OK</kbd> button will just do nothing until you have a valid address in the box or press <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

Comment: Oh well, I was hoping to prevent that, or actually replace with my own warning message, but I guess this is OK. I will for sure use that Cancel event :)

Comment: @ch1zra you can turn of **all** message boxes that come from that InputBox, but then you don't get any warnings at all. Replacing of the message is not possible. See my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

A possible modification to the suggested function:

```
Public Function IsAddressValid(myAddress As String) As Boolean
    On Local Error Resume Next
    IsAddressValid = Range(myAddress).Rows.Count > 0
End Function
```